# pandas.Series.str.contains - how to stop at first match?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with two columns (company_name and sales).

The `company_name` column includes the name of the company plus a short description (e.g. company X - medical insurance; company Y - travel and medical insurance; company Z - medical and holiday insurance etc.)

I want to add a third column with a binary classification (medical_insurance or travel_insurance) based on the first matching string value included in the company_name.

I have tried using `str.contains` but when matching words from different groups are present in the company_name column (e.g., medical and travel), `str.contains` doesn't necessarily classify it matching the first instance (which is what I need).

```
medical_focused = df.loc[df['company_name'].str.contains(
  'medical|hospital', flags=re.IGNORECASE, na=False),'classification'] = 'medical_focused'

travel_focused = df.loc[df['company_name'].str.contains(
  'travel|holiday', flags=re.IGNORECASE, na=False),'classification'] = 'travel_focused'
```

How can I force str.contains to stop at the first instance?

Thanks!

Comment: so you have some company names that contain, for instance, both `medical` and `travel`?

Comment: Hi @James yes, exactly! In cases where a company has both instances, the idea is that the first mention will determine the group to which it belongs (e.g. 'company X medical and travel insurance' should be part of the medical group, whereas 'company Y travel and medical insurance' should belong to the travel group).

Comment: My only idea would be  to use something like `...str.extract('^(.*?)medical|hospital', expand=False, ...)`, then apply `str.len` on the returned series to retrieve positions of first match of a relevant word (or NaN if not present).